# How to create progress bar in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, progress-bar

I am currently working in datatables with a lot of data (5000). To be able to load data with progress, I added a progress bar that states how much data has been loaded in each unit of time. But the code below is not working anymore.

```js
let handleProgressBar = (id, value, total) => {
    let percent = Math.round((value / total) * 10000) / 100;
    $(id + " > div").html(percent + "%");
    $(id + " > div").css('width', percent + "%");
}

let table = $('#data').DataTable();

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  res.forEach(async(data, index)=>{
    table.row.add([
      data.id,
      data.albumId,
      data.title,
      data.url
    ]);
    handleProgressBar('#progress-bar', index+1, res.length);
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1)); // sleep 1 ms
  });
  table.draw();
});
```

```css
.progress-bar-striped {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.progress-bar-striped>div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    /*-webkit-transition: width 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 3s ease;
    transition: width 3s ease;*/
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    background-color: #288ade;
}

.progress-bar-striped p {
    margin: 0;
}

@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 40px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar-striped">
    <div style="width: 0%;">
        <p>0%</p>
    </div>
</div>

<table id="data" class="table display table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Album ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>URL Photo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The table has been loaded successfully but the progress bar shows `100%` instead of should increment from `0%` to `100%`. I wonder about it works (*but not perfectly*) if I don't use datatable as shown in the code below.

```js
let handleProgressBar = (id, value, total) => {
    let percent = Math.round((value / total) * 10000) / 100;
    $(id + " > div").html(percent + "%");
    $(id + " > div").css('width', percent + "%");
}

(async() =>{
  let n = 5000;
  handleProgressBar('#progress-bar', 0, n);
  for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    handleProgressBar('#progress-bar', i, n);
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1)); // sleep 1 ms
  }
})();
```

```css
.progress-bar-striped {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.progress-bar-striped>div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    /*-webkit-transition: width 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 3s ease;
    transition: width 3s ease;*/
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    background-color: #288ade;
}

.progress-bar-striped p {
    margin: 0;
}

@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 40px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar-striped">
    <div style="width: 0%;">
        <p>0%</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea where the mistake is. Can anyone provide me with the perfect way to handle the progress bar for datatable with a lot of data? Thanks before.

Comment: But aside from all of that, I would recommend you consider using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for this type of scenario - where only one page of visible data is sent for each request (thus making a progress bar moot).

Comment: @andrewJames can you elaborate your explanation with a working fiddle? It would be helpful.

Comment: Why did you add a bounty on this question, even if you already solved it?

Comment: @Elikill58 Because I think my answer can be improved whether it's with a new answer or an improvement of an existing answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution. The mistake is I put the `async` word inside `res.forEach`. When I put it after `fetch.then` and use `for` loop instead of `forEach`, the behavior of function execution changed and can be done successfully. The `loadNumber` variable can be used for determining how much data which will draw in datatables per unit of time.

```js
let handleProgressBar = (id, value, total) => {
    let percent = Math.round((value / total) * 10000) / 100;
    $(id + " > div").html(percent + "%");
    $(id + " > div").css('width', percent + "%");
}

let table = $('#data').DataTable({
  dom: 'ilpftr'
});

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
.then((res) => res.json())
.then(async(res) => {
  let loadNumber = 50;
  for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    table.row.add([
      res[i].id,
      res[i].albumId,
      res[i].title,
      res[i].url
    ]);
    if (i % loadNumber == 0) {
      table.draw();
      handleProgressBar('#progress-bar', i+1, res.length);
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1)); // sleep 1 ms
    }
  }
  table.draw();
  handleProgressBar('#progress-bar', res.length, res.length);
});
```

```css
.progress-bar-striped {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.progress-bar-striped>div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    /*-webkit-transition: width 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 3s ease;
    transition: width 3s ease;*/
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    background-color: #288ade;
}

.progress-bar-striped p {
    margin: 0;
}

@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 40px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar-striped">
    <div style="width: 0%;">
        <p>0%</p>
    </div>
</div>

<table id="data" class="table display table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Album ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>URL Photo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice - glad you solved it. Thank you for sharing. I see now the CSS was slowing down the animations, previously. A similar but different approach (not claiming it is better) is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcnkpujy/) - it uses DataTables built-in support for Ajax. (But I do think this is still probably not really a true measurement of the user's wait time.)

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Wow, that's a nice example of using Ajax inside Datatable to load data. I appreciate it!